# Visual Studio “There is no editor available for” .cs

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I have problems opening my .cs file that contains 4000 lines of code... When I try to open it there is a message box that shows up saying: `There is no editor available for ... .cs`. I also tried to open that file in Notepad++ but all my code is replaced with `NULL` values !

There is no file in "C:\Users(your user name)\Documents\Visual Studio (year)\Backup Files\my project".

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 on a Virtual Machine.

Please Help !!!

Comment: If you go to a command prompt and the directory of your code and do "type myfile.cs" does it show text or lots of barf?

Comment: Visual Studio obviously works with big files. If the file is full of NULLs though, something corrupted the file. Most likely, a disk problem and/or chkdsk operation erased its contents. I hope you used git *and* a backup remote repo

Comment: Even if the file wasn't killed by a disk problem, you still can't recover it unless you used version control

Comment: @BugFinder it prints lots of empty lines...

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I didn't use version control ... damn !

Comment: Maybe a system restore will fix it?

Comment: _"...4000 lines of code....I didn't use version control..."_ - there's really no excuse for that

Comment: @Valip that a unique opportunity to rewrite the code in a more modular fashion. There's no good reason to create a 4K line file.

Comment: What if I use Reflector or dotPeeks? Should they help with something?

Comment: If the file is empty (which it clearly is) you need to locate another copy of the file.. do you have a backup? (Visual studio doesnt really do backups for you.. I mean a proper backup where you copied files off your machine)